# How to change the redis target when i swap my app service in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, redis, azure-web-app-service

I'm using the Microsoft app service to deploy my web application,

and it have staging.domain.com and www.domain.com,

but now they are both link to the same redis,

How to I let them link to different redis, when I swap them?

I think it can solved by the app setting.

Is there any best solution or suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

As shown here in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing#configuration-for-deployment-slots), you can set different settings on different deployment slots in Web Apps, and set them "sticky". That will make them stay in the deployment slot. If you don't mark them sticky, they will swap with the app.

> To configure an app setting or connection string to stick to a slot (not swapped), access the Application Settings blade for a specific slot, then select the Slot Setting box for the configuration elements that should stick the slot. Note that marking a configuration element as slot specific has the effect of establishing that element as not swappable across all the deployment slots associated with the app.